# Service Bus queue to keep last message

Tags: azureservicebus, servicebus

is there a way to configure service bus queue/subscription to only hold the last message, and throw away any older, irrespective of time.

This is so the client gets the latest 'state' whenever it connects, without having to store all messages since it last connected (which would cause performance problems when disconnected for a long period)

Thanks,
Stevo

Comment: Can you give more detail ? If you want to just keep 1 message why you are using queue ?

Comment: Because by using a queue/subscription push mechanism, I get live updates whenever there is a new message (state). The target is not to have a queue, it's to have a subscription mechanism for multiple clients to receive live updates, and ideally to get the latest state on connecting. I appreciate there are different technologies perhaps more suited for this, or a combination of more technologies. The question is can service bus do this out-of-box

Answer (score 2):

Service Bus doesn't have that a feature; some brokers have such a concept (e.g. retained messages in MQTT brokers), but it's a tricky capability for a range of reasons. One of those is that you'd suddenly turn a Queue into a broadcast entity, and the semantics of settlement (completion) would have to change completely. There's also a bunch of potential authorization issues. Who gets to override the sticky message? Any sender?

A clean way to handle this is to put the shared state information into a Blob that everyone knows to walk up to when come up uninitialized, and then listen on a Service Bus Topic Subscription to find out when there is a new version of the Blob information (and that information may just as well be inlined into the payload if it fits).

If you need to know whether the message from the subscription is younger or older than the Blob you just picked up, compare the Blob timestamp and the message's EnqueuedTimeUtc and toss out stale messages.